One Playwright config mulipile test folders in an NX monorepo
I have an NX monorepo. I want to use Playwright across all of my project. However I don't want one test folder in the root. I want to have multiple test folders in each project in packages and app. Is there a good way to do this?

Simply put multiple test folders in each project. I'm not sure I understand the issue here. Maybe showing your folder structure and sample config/tests/packages etc would help.
